# Enable TRACE in custom DFS application (DfLogger, log4j)

Tags: java, log4j, documentum, documentum-dfs

**Summary**

We're struggling with enabling log4j's TRACE level in a custom Documentum DFS application. The application runs on Tomcat 7.0 and uses Log4j 1.2.13, and is packaged as a WAR archive.

We have an appender called `CustomServiceAppender` that works just fine with all the other levels, i.e. DEBUG and upwards. During development we have this appender configured for the DEBUG level, and for production we change it to INFO or WARN. The logging then behaves like we expect (it limits the logging).

However we have written some code that logs at the TRACE level that we want to see in our logs. We've tried restarting, redeploying, deleting cache, checking log4j and commons-logging versions (they are 1.2.13 and 1.1.1, respectively). Also, there is no XML configuration file, and we know that our properties file is being picked up.

We use the default logger from DFS, namely the `DfLogger` class.

---

**Changing the configuration - why doesn't it work?**

In `log4j.properties` we change the following line *from*

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.services=DEBUG,CustomerServiceAppender
```

*to*

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.services=TRACE,CustomerServiceAppender
```

... which does not work! However, *the following does work*:

```
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.services=INFO,CustomerServiceAppender
```

What's happening here? Why can't we enable TRACE?

---

**log4j.properties**

For reference, here's our complete configuration file (identifying names altered):

```
#------------------- COMMON LOGGING LEVELS --------------------------
log4j.logger.com.emc.documentum.fs.rt = WARN, A1, F1
log4j.logger.com.emc.documentum.fs.datamodel = WARN, A1, F1
log4j.logger.com.emc.documentum.fs.services = WARN, A1, F1
log4j.logger.com.emc.documentum.fs.tools = WARN, A1, F1
log4j.logger.com.documentum.debug=ERROR, A1, F1
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, A1

#------------------- CONSOLE LOG --------------------------
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.services=ERROR,A1
log4j.appender.A1.Threshold=ERROR
log4j.appender.A1=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.A1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.A1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [MYCOMPANY-SP] %c - %m%n

#------------------- ALL --------------------------
log4j.appender.F1=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.F1.File=E\:/Documentum/logs/dfs-runtime.log
log4j.appender.F1.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.F1.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.F1.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [MYCOMPANY-SP] %c- %m%n

#------------------- ASPECT_TRACE --------------------------
log4j.logger.com.emc.documentum.fs.tracing = DEBUG, ASPECT_TRACE
log4j.appender.ASPECT_TRACE=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.ASPECT_TRACE.File=E\:/Documentum/logs/dfs-runtime-trace.log
log4j.appender.ASPECT_TRACE.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.ASPECT_TRACE.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.ASPECT_TRACE.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601}  %5p [MYCOMPANY-SP] %m%n

#------------------- Customer TBO --------------------------
log4j.logger.no.customer=DEBUG,CustomerTBOAppender
log4j.appender.CustomerTBOAppender=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CustomerTBOAppender.File=E\:/Documentum/logs/CustomerTBO.log
log4j.appender.CustomerTBOAppender.MaxFileSize=10MB
log4j.appender.CustomerTBOAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CustomerTBOAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [MYCOMPANY-SP] [%t] %c - %m%n

#------------------- Customer Service --------------------------
log4j.logger.com.mycompany.services=TRACE,CustomerServiceAppender
log4j.appender.CustomerServiceAppender=org.apache.log4j.DailyRollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.CustomerServiceAppender.File=E\:/Documentum/logs/CustomerService.log
log4j.appender.CustomerServiceAppender.Append=true
log4j.appender.CustomerServiceAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CustomerServiceAppender.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ISO8601} %5p [MYCOMPANY-SP] [%t] %c - %m%n

****************************************************************************************
```

Comment: are you sure you are using the right libs? as you can see on this [link](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/Level.html#TRACE) TRACE level is used from the version 1.2.12 while other logging levels (more or less) are available from the start of library.

Comment: I'll have an extra, hard look at version numbers. I also saw that TRACE was introduced in 1.2.12, so that was my first suspicion as well.